# Visual Studio Code - Java Classpath is incomplete. Only syntax errors will be reported

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am making my first steps with java, after some extensive experiences with python. The script I am running is a simple Java Swing Gui, that compiles and runs fine from the command line and within VS Code.

To set up the java debug environment, I used the lauch.json settings suggested on the github site https://github.com/k--kato/vscode-javadebug.

Unfortunately, every time I open the folder that contains the script, I get the following error message:

```
Warn: Classpath is incomplete. Only syntax errors will be reported.
```

I have no idea if the problem comes from within VS Code, of if it's some other configuration issue, such as the java set up....

My working platform is Linux Ubuntu, Gnome Shell.

Can anybody help?

This is the script:

```
//file name = SimpleEx.java 

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleEx extends JFrame {

    public SimpleEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setTitle("Simple example");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            SimpleEx ex = new SimpleEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

and this is my launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasename}",
            "options": [
                "-classpath",
                "${fileDirname}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Console App",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "startupClass": "${fileBasename}",
            "options": [
                 "-classpath",
                 "${fileDirname}"
            ],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but the Java ecosystem is very, very rich and mature. There are at least 3 free Java IDEs that are way more advanced than VSCode. I'd strongly suggest using one of those (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans).

Comment: thanks, JB, I'm considering .... still would like to stick with VS Code, but I will definitely give them a try ..

Comment: I am getting the exact same warning. And mine is just a simple Hello World console app!

Comment: See the discussion on the vscode-java extension project.  https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/107

Comment: Workaround for daily jobs is difficult. I ended with Intellij CE

Comment: Open src folder in vscode and you won't see this error.

Comment: I had this same problem on a new arm based linux machine and I had to make sure my JAVA_HOME was set to JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.18.0-openjdk-arm64 in /etc/environment. Then with a maven project I was able to run with no issues. I had to restart my machine and not use the source command to get it into the environment correctly. Assuming you are using Java 18.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is an old question, but anyone who stumbles here and needs a quick and easy fix may find it here. Install the extension: **Eclipse New Java Project**.

It emulates the behavior of the Eclipse action **create Java Project** and should produce the results you need.

Just press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type New Java Project (it will pop up after a few letters) and follow the simple directions. (it just asks for the name of the project).

It will create the project and files needed and you won't have to worry about that classpath error.
Then just create your class files as normal in the `src` folder of your new project and proceed with your programming!

Comment: I follow this steps but It create only 2 folder src and bin.

Answer (score 15):

In **VS Code** just right-click on the src (Your Project Source Folder) and select the **" Add folder to Java source path"** option. If it didn't' worked, then try to remove it first by selecting **"remove the folder from Java source path"** (this will not result in any data loss) and then adding it again.

Restart once when done.
Hope it works for you.

[image]

Comment: This simple trick works for me! Upvoted for more people to see

Comment: I wish I saw this earlier.

Comment: When using maven, I get "Unsupported operation. Please use pom.xml file to manage the source directories of maven project."

Answer (score 12):

Since the Microsoft Visual Studio Code ecosystem is rapidly evolving for Java, there is a handy solution that enormously helps to generate - in just a few steps - a functioning Java project structure to use with VS Code.

There are, of course other solutions to work with Java, like NetBeans, but I have always liked VS Code a lot and just waited until something more easy came up to get back to using it.

The quite easy solution I found is using MAVEN. Maven creates the whole project structure and initial configuration files in your home folder and you can immediately open it with VS Code and run it without any hassle.

Of course, you will have to have the Java extensions installed, as explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java).

The solution I found [here](https://gorkem1.gitbooks.io/visual-studio-code-for-java/chapter-1/Maven-Create.html) on the net was a little outdated, so I have made some adaptations.

This is the process on a Linux machine:

1. Check if you have MAVEN installed

   - Type into a terminal:

     ```
     mvn --version
     ```
   - If maven is not installed, the output will suggest the installation command;
2. Invoke the maven quickstart archetype to generate your new project;

   - Inside the terminal type or copy:

     ```
     mvn archetype:generate
     ```
   - This will open a scary list of over 2000 achetypes to choose from. The good news is that if you don't fill in a number, maven-archetype-quickstart will be automatically selected, so just press ENTER.
   - Choose a version from the list and type in the number: I picked the suggested number = 6
   - Choose a value for property groupId:

     ```
     com.mycompany.app
     ```
   - Define a value for property 'artifactId' (this will create the folder in your home directory) :

     ```
     my-app
     ```
   - Define value for 'version' :  1.0
   - Define value for property 'package' :

     ```
     com.mycompany.app
     ```
   - Confirm the options and the project will be generated.
3. Start VS Code with the new project

   - In the terminal type :

     ```
     code ./my-app
     ```
4. Configure a Launch.json file

   - In the top left of the debugger, on the right side of the green, where it says "no configuration", choose "Java" from the drop-down field and the .json file will be auto-generated.
5. Configure a Task.json

   - Go to Task in the menu bar;
   - Configure tasks ......
   - Create task.json from template ....
   - Select "maven" from the drop-down list and the .json file will be auto-generated.

You are good to go.

Answer (score 11):

This warning is displayed when you open a java file that the [redhat.java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension can not determine a classpath for. To get the full benefits of the extension use either a project with maven pom.xml (soon also gradle), or least default eclipse setting files aka *.classpath* *.project* files.

Comment: A more detailed explanation is available in the project Wiki: 
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/%22Classpath-is-incomplete%22-warning

Answer (score 9):

I got this error along with `Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json` during compilation.

All I had to do was open `Command Palette` in `View` or with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and then run the command `Clean Java Server Language Workspace` and everything started working normally again.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

searching for this i found that vscode right now only recognizes maven projects, or eclipse projects so it needs a .classpath file. So the best option is create the project with maven first and then open with vscode.

Comment: Thank you all, guys, for your suggestions. Using InteliJ now,, works out-of-the-box with no hussing for configurations.

Answer (score 4):

i know it's too late but you can simply solve this if you convert your project to eclipse with this simple command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (assuming you are using maven) at your root directory this will add `.classpath` file. in this case your `src/*` files will be project files

**Tested on vscode and coc-java in vim too**

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else, I have to change this line in .classpath

```
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
```

to

```
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main">
```

I just had to change the path and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Just press ctrl+shift+p and type Create Java Project and then click no build tools
and it will ask to Select folder, then choose the folder and it ask for creating the file name, give the name to file It will create the project and files needed and you won't have to worry about that classpath error. Then just create your class files as normal in the src folder of your new project and proceed with your programming!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this issue and resolved it on my own. I was trying to compile and run my java file from outside of the folder it was inside. That's when I got the same "classpath" error op mentioned above. Once I moved into the directory in which the files were located, I was able to run without issue.

Answer (score 1):

create .vscode/settings.json with the following content:

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "<project_path>/src"
    ],
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "<libs_path>/**/*.jar"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the users facing this issue using visual studio code, you can try uninstalling the java extension you have been using and reinstall it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30536691)